# How to use dot as thousand separator in Django

Tags: python, django

In my `settings.py` I have following code:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en' 
USE_I18N = True    
USE_L10N = True
USE_DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = True
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ","
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = "."
```

And in my template I use the number as follows:

```
{% load humanize %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load l10n %}
<div>{% trans "Price" %}: € <b>{{ payment|floatformat:2|intcomma }}</b></div>
```

But still the number is **18,300.00** and I want that it is **18.300,00**.

Any idea?

Comment: You are applying `intcomma` in addition to it, that could be the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The following is noted in the [documentation about **DECIMAL_SEPARATOR**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#decimal-separator) setting:

```
Default: '.' (Dot)

Default decimal separator used when formatting decimal numbers.
```

> Note that if `USE_L10N` is set to `True`, then the locale-dictated format has 
>   higher precedence and will be applied instead.

Since `USE_L10N` is set, the number format set for the locale is preferred when rendering a number.

As far as I know the current desired format for numbers isn't available in English language locale. I find that format in used in Deutsch language locale.

The `language` template tag allows you to [switch language in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates).

```
{% load humanize %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load l10n %}
<div>{% trans "Price" %}: 
{% language 'de' %}
€ <b>{{ payment|floatformat:2|intcomma }}</b>
{% endlanguage %}
</div>
```